# To show that a given number is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $1010101...01$, where there are $2016$ zeros, is a prime number.
The number alternates between $1$'s and $0$'s and ends in a $1$. The total number of zeros showing up is $2016$.

Now this number is of the form $4k+1$,which shows that it might be a prime number but how do I show that its a prime and by Wilson's theorem it would be too big to compute.

Any idea would be truly appreciated.

Comment: So that would be $\frac{10^{4034}-1}{99}$, I suppose. And you are aware that "$4k+1$" practically only says that it is not a multiple of $2$, aren't you?

Comment: ...which is certainly not prime, as the numerator is a difference of perfect squares, and hence factors.

Comment: Indeed, no number of the form $1010\cdots 1$ is prime, except for $101$.

Comment: The OP number is a multiple of 80681, if someone cares to check :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was just about to ask how you see that for the odd-number-of-zeroes case, but of course those guys are multiples of $101$ :)

Comment: @Hagen: Travis' argument seems to work for both even and odd numbers of zeroes. You still get $10^{2n}-1$ in the numerator no matter the parity of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.I got my answer.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Pari GP says "(10^4034-1)%80681 = 0" - hooray! :-).

Answer (score 2):

Writing up answer implied by someone else's comment in the vain hope that this question won't hang around cluttering up the 'unanswered list' forever.

The decimal number $101010\cdots10101$ ($n$ pairs of $10$ followed by $1$) contains $n+1$ ones separated by zeroes. If we multiply it by $99$ we get $999\cdots999$, i.e. $2(n+1)$ nines, or $10^{2n+2}-1$. So the original number can be written as $\dfrac{10^{2n+2}-1}{99} = \dfrac{(10^{n+1})^2-1}{99} = \dfrac{(10^{n+1}-1)(10^{n+1}+1)}{99}$.

If $n$ is odd, it factorises as $\left(\dfrac{10^{n+1}-1}{99}\right)\left(10^{n+1}+1\right)$ where both factors are integers.

If $n$ is even, it factorises as $\left(\dfrac{10^{n+1}-1}{9}\right)\left(\dfrac{10^{n+1}+1}{11}\right)$ where both factors are integers.

So the original number is composite, except in the case of $n=1$ (original number is $101$) where one of the factors is 1.